# Cannot restore variables from saved variables, TensorFlow 1.0, python 3.5.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I new to tensorflow, when I try to restore saved parameters from saved variables I got **"NotFoundError: Key b_1 not found in checkpoint"** the complete code is at below. Thank you for your help!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
## save to a file
## need to use the same shape and dtype when restore
W = tf.Variable([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]], dtype=tf.float32, name='W')
b = tf.Variable([[1,2,3]],dtype=tf.float32, name='b') 


# initialization
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver.save(sess, 'C:\Temp\TensorFlow\save\save.ckpt')
```

Below is the restore part:
    ## restore variables

```
W = tf.Variable(np.arange(6).reshape((2,3)), dtype=tf.float32, name='W')
b = tf.Variable(np.arange(3).reshape((1,3)), dtype=tf.float32, name='b')    


saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, 'C:\Temp\TensorFlow\save\save.ckpt')
    print('weights', sess.run(W))
    print('biases', sess.run(b))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) is to save (or restore) every variable in [`tf.all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/all_variables) (in addition to any other "saveable objects") using their [`name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#name) property as a key.

I suspect that if you print out `W.name` and `b.name` in the restore part of your program, you will get `"W_1"` and `"b_1"`. Why do you get these names when you specified `name='W'` and `name='b'`? There must have already been variables with those names in the current TensorFlow graph, and so TensorFlow assumes that you were intentionally creating new variables, and appends a suffix (`"_1"`, `"_2"`, etc.) to make the name unique. For example, if you ran the two code fragments from your question one after the other in the same script (or Jupyter notebook), you would see this problem.

There are a few ways to avoid this problem:

1. An easy but crude way is to call [`tf.reset_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/reset_default_graph) before the restore part of your program. This resets the current graph to being empty, so the variables will end up having the names `"W"` and `"b"` as you intended.
2. You can achieve a similar effect by wrapping the restore part in a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` block, which ensures the variables are created in an empty graph.
3. You can override the mapping between variables in the checkpoint and `tf.Variable` objects by passing a `var_list` argument to the `tf.train.Saver` constructor as follows:

   ```
   saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list={"W": W, "b", b})
   ```

Comment: I tried these steps you mentioned, but it did not work. Still the same error. Did my code run at your side? Thanks!

Comment: Yes: [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/mrry/01e2de711e62c84018a7c6102925c5ec) that worked for me (modified for Linux, so you'd have to change the paths, but that's all). [EDIT: I also just noticed that that ":0" in the variable keys was incorrect, and updated the answer to reflect that. That might fix your problem....]